# iCorousel auto scrolling example does not work with icorousal type linear

Tags: ios, objective-c, autoscroll, icarousel

Any idea how we can make it work. 
I have not changed the working code but tried replacing the type:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //configure carousel
    _carousel.type = iCarouselTypeLinear;

    //start scrolling
    [self startScrolling];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes It's not working for me too and in the iCarouselExampleViewController.m, Issue is with

```
    [self startScrolling];
```

when    [self startScrolling]; is commented out,leaving out auto scroll, at the least carousel works.

<s>Working on it. Once i solve will update the post.</s> Just add case iCarouselOptionWrap: return Yes; as mentioned below. It would solve the problem.

```
    - (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel valueForOption:(iCarouselOption)option withDefault:(CGFloat)value
    {
        switch (option)
        {
            case iCarouselOptionSpacing:
                return value * 1.1;
            case iCarouselOptionWrap:
                return Yes;
            default:
                return value;
        }
    }
```

Slightly tweaking is needed to

```
    - (void)scrollStep
```

to make it work without enabling wrap per se adding condition to check the current item and reload the scroll.